# JTable when searched - not getting right ID

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablerowsorter

So I'm trying to after searching a name click on the table and then edit it in other table, the problem is that I'm not getting the right ID but instead only getting the ID that is the first.

[JTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnNIq.png)

[Search in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHAyG.png)

[ID wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge1SB.png)

**Edit Code**

```
int linha = this.jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int idUtilizador = Integer.parseInt((String)(this.jTable1.getModel() ).getValueAt(linha, 0));
Utilizador uti = UtilizadorJpaController.read(idUtilizador);
CriarCliente updateCliente = new CriarCliente(uti);
updateCliente.setVisible(true);
```

**Search Code**

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
jTable1.setRowSorter(tr);
tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(jTextField1.getText().trim(),1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sort or filter a table, the data in the `TableModel` doesn't change. Only the view of the data changes.

If you want to get the data from the model, then you need to convert the "view row" to the "model row" by using the `convertRowIndexToModel(...)` method:

```
int linha = this.jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int modelRow = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(linha);
int idUtilizador = Integer.parseInt((String)(this.jTable1.getModel() ).getValueAt(modelRow, 0));
//int idUtilizador = Integer.parseInt((String)(this.jTable1.getModel() ).getValueAt(linha, 0));
```

Also, why are you using Integer.parseInt(...)? If the data in the model is an integer value, then it should be stored as an Integer value, not a String value.